# How to do git cherry-pick --continue in SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-cherry-pick

How do I continue cherry picking using SourceTree after I resolved conflicts?

If I am doing rebase and I get conflicts then after resolving them when I click commit SourceTree lets me continue that rebase. But how to continue cherry pick operation?

Answer (score 50):

`cherry-pick` effectively applies the changes from commit A onto the working tree and makes a commit. This means if you get any conflicts during `cherry-pick`ing you need to `commit` after resolving them to finish the `cherry-pick`.

**EDIT** Edward noted that this is only true when you are `cherry-pick`ing a single commit. When picking multiple commits you can run `git cherry-pick --continue` from the console. I'm not sure if you can do this directly via SourceTree.

Comment: No, that's only true when you cherry pick a single commit; `cherry-pick --continue` is what you need to run when you are cherry picking multiple commits.

Comment: @EdwardThomson You're right. I totally forgot that you can cherry pick multiple commits since I never do this. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: If you look at the console, "fix conflicts and run "git cherry-pick --continue." When fixing conflicts the normal way (without the cherry-pick), the console will mention to commit (after the conflicts have been fixed). As such, even with a single cherry-pick, I think that `git cherry-pick --continue` is the way to go. I filed https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-3133.

Comment: Actually, to nit-pick, it's not `cherry-pick --continue` but `git cherry-pick --continue`. Sometimes helpful for us noobs out there.

Comment: How do you even cherry-pick several commits in SourceTree btw?

Comment: My answer isn't really specifically about SourceTree. I'm a command line purist and don't use a GUI to work with git, so sadly I can't help you.

Comment: if you often need running `git cherry-pick --continue` in SOurceTree, you can create a Custom Action for this.

Comment: run: git commit

Answer (score 22):

Create a custom action as such

```sh
git cherry-pick --continue --no-edit
```