# Why does git cherry-pick not continue?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I am trying to cherry-pick changes from two different working brachnes to each other namely I want to cherry-pick the last 5 commits from branch `linear` to branch `diagonal`.

```
git cherry-pick -n -x linear~6..linear
```

As expected there are some merging conflicts for the first cherry-picked commit. I figure them out e.g. with `git status`, resolve them and update the index with `git add`.
Now I want to continue with the rest but

```
git cherry-pick --continue`
```

leads to (sorry it is translated, english error message may be slightly different):

```
error: Your local changes will be overwritten by "cherry-pick".
Note: Stash your changes by using "stash" in order to continue.
fatal: "cherry-pick" failed.
```

What did I do wrong? **How do I resolve conflicts but still commit a cherry-pick from several commits in only *one* commit?** This is important for me as several of these commits will be undone by following commits.

---

This might be a duplicate of ["How to do git cherry-pick --continue in SourceTree?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306597/how-to-do-git-cherry-pick-continue-in-sourcetree) but I do not see my question answered there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you have already fixed the conflict file, you need to add it first to continue with git-cherry pick.

```
git add <modified file-name>
git commit -m "committing changes for file"
git cherry-pick --continue
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: no this does not help. As stated above, I excatly did this, but it lead to the translated error message. Even though `git status` says that there are no unstaged changes.

Comment: Did you commit the modified file ? Please post output of git status

Comment: no, I did not commit, as the changes should be all done in one commit. (see above). The cherry-pick command says, that this should be possible.

Comment: @benni : I believe you have to commit the changes and then continue with git cherry pick, however you don't have to push them to repository. Changes should be added to the commit object only after "git add". once you are done with successful "git cherry-pick --continue" , then push them all at once.

Comment: "git add", "git stash ...", "git cherry-pick --continue", then pop your stash. That worked for me.

Comment: I think the reason it didn't work is because of the "-n" (no commit) flag. Git never enters "cherry pick" mode and thus the --continue doesn't work.